# Can’t submit data to API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I have a controller through which I send data to my local environment of the api platform (which is running fine)

```
    /**
     * Creates a new Location entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->get("suvya_breadcrumbs.factory")->update('New Hub');

        $form = $this->createForm(HubType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $new_url = $this->generateUrl('new_hub');
        $redirect_url = $this->generateUrl('home');

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
            ]);

            $response = $client->request('POST', '/hubs', [
                'form_params'=> $form->getData(),
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept'     => 'application/ld+json',
                    'Content-Type'=> 'application/json',
                    'Authorization'=> 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzg3NjE1NCwiZXhwIjoxNTE3ODc5NzU0fQ.gIG9lueJJZxzkOl8qblhHWwiJvW97m4gz1-1mYeM9SgMzMW35Wh6XamOOYiISDN99yJ6Ovo-wKk6whpE5UGMDVw_wGek003Dd6r-Y7Ql3kVLHksn2JFzhAN3GwlXFcOI4MIjmq5qBhkzv21pHymO0yn1SlzWBwb0O7WygywefMu5p09zGuvAiP9I2ShyQLZhjj8bB_odf3dI-Ql0ZbRmn_JDkDoPcm5U11i-3S1oMikBmFq0WtTcWo7vezt3QdA3bY4_bgaISINAiYRR-_cvjpBSqFSE6n1ZYtHvKFn-98wXXsBGxEAoZw6iQL4iRgOI8F_uaiCo0eRHC7q0_xQ_V_W0-5XDIQXWDwoiVaUXnjO6xo2Fldp7PLO1ueJz1e4wiOy2-TunZdc8UCtw2BdFIQtWatPLi_v_rsNvF2H-6hwa9UOKEi9Z4tH4KkuATbXAxxfkCbSOyY1SAWP0riooPQi_AI2J7L2Ly86eAuKo1Hix3EuEogo19GSyBz_cCWczyERQWM9gikuUs8E22SIAdxTl8ZLFaXgiZIibDvb8pqcN8izFjywWbF2CkyWC58WxrVd6Bfmfnm7k9T6oZqwIZ-TQR-SbRnUHN1hpWUjFCk-tHhgvh7osHXmxe3grzA8M3LPBpQGQiTeqBZFMjF4Tx8zW2tuiEn6TwhV14Lj24Vc'
                ]
            ]);

            die();
        }

        return $this->render('SuvyaFabricsCloudBundle:Common:basic.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'page_title'=> 'Hub aanmaken',
            'action_path' => $new_url,
            'cancel_path'=> $redirect_url,
            'submit_button_title'  => 'Opslaan',
        ));
    }
```

But unfortunately i'm getting an error in my dev.log of the api environment:

```
[2018-02-06 02:32:37] request.INFO: Matched route "api_hubs_post_collection". {"route":"api_hubs_post_collection","route_parameters":{"_controller":"api_platform.action.post_collection","_format":null,"_api_resource_class":"AppBundle\\Entity\\Hub","_api_collection_operation_name":"post","_route":"api_hubs_post_collection"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/hubs","method":"POST"} []
[2018-02-06 02:32:37] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: "Syntax error" at /Users/myname/Sites/suvyalogistics-api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/JsonDecode.php line 78 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Exception\\UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Syntax error at /Users/myname/Sites/suvyalogistics-api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/JsonDecode.php:78)"} []
```

The output of form->getData():

```
array (size=4)
  'postalCode' => string 'sdfdsf' (length=6)
  'streetName' => string 'sdfsdf' (length=6)
  'doorNumber' => string 'sdfsfd' (length=6)
  'city' => string 'sdfsfd' (length=6)
```

Running the endpoint at the api platform with the same values goes fine as well.

Does anyone of you has an idea why this goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a payload encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (HTML form like) to the API Platform API, while, according to the headers you've set, it excepts data encoded in JSON.

To encode the data of the form in JSON, you can use the following Guzzle snippet:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', '/hubs', [
    'json' => $form->getData(),
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/ld+json',
        'Authorization'=> '...'
    ]
]);
```

Alternatively, you can [configure API Platform to accept form data](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/form-data/), but I would not recommend going this way (it's better to only deal with JSON API-side).